# Asynchronous response of functions (callback). How to apply?

Tags: javascript

I need to get the first response of "second" function, then the "first" function.

```
function first(n,callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(n);
    }, 1000);
    callback();
}

function callback() {
    console.log('2');
}

first(5,callback);
```

Comment: hi! Judging by your name (so sorry if I'm wrong) you might find it easier to ask questions a [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Put the `callback()` call inside the function that you pass to `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.resolve` and execute `setTimeout` inside the `resolve` & inside `then` callback execute the `callback`

```js
function first(n, callback) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(console.log(n)), 1000)).then(() => {
    callback()
  })

}

function callback() {
  console.log('2');
}

first(5, callback);
```